# No Response Data in REST Spring Boot and Apache web server

Tags: spring, apache, rest, http-proxy

There are many REST services running which are Spring boot projects and are proxied via **Apache Web Server**. Now I am facing below issues:- 
 1. Randomly I get **Response body does not contain any data** but HTTP status Code is proper. So, why there is **No Body** even though the server is setting up the Body. In apache I just do ProxyPass /test http://localhost:7000/test

2. The response headers sometimes have **Connection close** and sometime **keep Alive**. Why there is a difference in Request header?
Do I need to modify any default settings of ApacheServer? Can this happen due to Load on Apache Server? Can someone please give some pointers as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing similar issue. Suddenly my spring boot application is not responding. Day before it was fine. I am developing JSF appliation - using Spring boot and primefaces. I remember, I was updating xhtml page and during deploying below stack-trace was thrown -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resources may not be accessed if they are not currently started
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.validate(StandardRoot.java:245)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResource(ApplicationContext.java:554)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResource(ApplicationContextFacade.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.exists(ServletContextResource.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.addStaticIndexHtmlViewControllers(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:276)
```

Note that I was using Spring boot 1.2.6.RELEASE, so I updated pom.xml to use latest version 1.3.3.RELEASE. Now deploy was successful, but Chrome web browser gets no response and blank page displayed. However, Firefox give below error in the page -

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.xhtml Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

Changed from embedded Tomcat to Jetty, but Jetty provides below stack-track during deploying -

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Faces Servlet@87ee159b==javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet,1,false
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:637)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext$JettyEmbeddedServletHandler.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:36)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.handleDeferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.start(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:114)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:555)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:616)
```

Any light into this is highly appreciated.